# Grid column definitions

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, layout, grid

Inside the same `StackPanel` I'd like to put a control aligned on the left and another one on the right side. I made an attempt using a `Grid` and defining `ColumnDefinitions` but with no luck.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="72" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                             <Button />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Button Height="72" Width="72" />     
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
```

The first column usually will take from 50% to 80% of the total width (depending on the content), while the second column will always take 72px. How can I set the first column so that it fills the total `Grid` width minus 72px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Width` property of the first column to `Star`:

```
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
```

Making the change in your code should work:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Height="72" Width="72" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Your solution worked great. However my previous code is now working as well since I removed the root StackPanel.